# How to set the throttle input of a vehicle in UE4 using acceleration/speed data from SUMO?

Tags: unreal-engine4, throttling, sumo, unreal-blueprint

Hi everyone (and thank you in advance)!

I  have successfully connected SUMO into UE4 using network sockets, with the intention of using UE4's superior graphics to run my SUMO simulation. I have managed to get the location, speed, angle, and acceleration (amongst other bits of information) of each of the SUMO vehicles across to UE4, and assigned this information to different vehicles in UE4 (i.e. each SUMO vehicle has a replica in UE4).

I have (I am pretty sure) managed to replicate the steering in SUMO in UE4, and I have managed to ensure that vehicles start at the same location in both programmes, but I am confused as to how I can match the speeds of the vehicles in UE4 and SUMO so that the vehicles are at the same location at the same time (which they need to be as they are turning at the same time).

Unless I have missed something really basic (I may have as I am fairly new to UE4 and SUMO), I don't think that there is a set velocity node for vehicles, whilst I don't think that the "Move to" node works for skeletal meshes. Of course, I could use the "Set Actor Location and Rotation" node, however, for vehicles, I have to teleport the object, which defeats the point of creating a realistic-looking simulation.

So... my question is, in short, "Is there a way of taking a speed/acceleration value and using this value to set the speed a vehicle moves at in UE4?"

Comment: What's wrong with vehicle.setSpeed https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html#VehicleDomain-setSpeed ?

Comment: Hi Michael (and thank you for the response)! Sorry, I think I may have phrased the question in a way that was slightly confusing! I want to set the speeds of the vehicles in Unreal to match that of vehicles in SUMO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a direct way of setting the velocity of the vehicle actors from SUMO, but a workaround, albeit a slightly annoying solution, is to use static meshes for the vehicles instead. Using the positional "x" and "y" information that SUMO outputs, one can then use the "Move Component To" node in UE4 over time delta (which is the frequency information is sent from SUMO) to get the vehicle static meshes to move in a way that looks similar to how a vehicle would move.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).